# Regex matching failing while attempting to read from file (SIC assembler in java)

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently working on a SIC assembler and scanning lines from the following file:

```
begin   START   0
main    LDX     zero
copy    LDCH    str1, x
        STCH    str2, x
        TIX     eleven
        JLT     copy

str1    BYTE    C'TEST STRING'
str2    RESB    11
zero    WORD    0
eleven  WORD    11
        END     main
```

I'm using, as you might have already guessed, a regex to extract the fields from each line of code. Right now, I'm just testing if the lines match the regex (as they're supposed to). If they do, the program prints them. The problem is, it just recognizes the first line, and ignores the rest (i. e. from the second line on, they do not match the regex).
Here's the code so far:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/home/daniel/test.asm"));
    Pattern std = Pattern.compile("(^$|[a-z0-9\\-\\_]*)(\\s+)([A-Z]+)(\\s+)([a-z0-9\\-\\_]*)");
    String lineFromFile;

    lineFromFile = scan.nextLine();
    Matcher standard = std.matcher(lineFromFile);

    while (standard.find()) {
        System.out.println(lineFromFile);
        lineFromFile = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

It prints just the first line:

```
begin   START   0
```

The weird thing comes here: if I copy the second line directly from the file, and declare a String object with it, and test it manually, it does work! And the same with the rest of the other lines. Something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/home/daniel/test.asm"));
    Pattern std = Pattern.compile("(^$|[a-z0-9\\-\\_]*)(\\s+)([A-Z]+)(\\s+)([a-z0-9\\-\\_]*)");
    String lineFromFile;

    lineFromFile = "main    LDX     zero";
    Matcher standard = std.matcher(lineFromFile);

    if (standard.find())
        System.out.println(lineFromFile);
}
```

And it does prints it!

```
main    LDX     zero
```

I don't know if it has something to do with the regex, or the file. I'd really appreciate if any of you guys help me to find the error.
Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: you are doing it wrong..see **[here](http://ideone.com/JGTS59)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE** :- I am assuming your regex is correct

You need to update the `Matcher` object for every line you read from input. (*For demonstration, I have just updated your code to read line by line from console and not file.*)

*Java Code*

```
String pattern = "(^$|[a-z0-9\\-\\_]*)(\\s+)([A-Z]+)(\\s+)([a-z0-9\\-\\_]*)"; 

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

String line = "";
Matcher m;
while((line = tmp.nextLine()) != null) {
    m = r.matcher(line);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + m.group(2)+ m.group(3)+ m.group(4)+ m.group(5));
    }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/sjm0CP)**

Though, use of `if` will be sufficient here until there are multiple matches on single line

```
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + m.group(2)+ m.group(3)+ m.group(4)+ m.group(5));
}
```

**EDIT**

Assuming only three part in your input, you can use this regex instead

```
^((?:\w+)?\s+)(\w+\s+)(.*)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU8uM6/1)**

Comment: I didn't know I had to refresh the matcher every time! Thank you very very much! :D

Comment: @DanielStark as every time there is different line for processing, that's why you need to update matcher

Answer (score 2):

Your regex does appear to be incorrect, but that's not your immediate problem.  Your `while` loop has to iterate through *all* lines, not just the ones that match.  If you're using a Scanner, the test condition is the `hasNextLine()` method.  You do the matching inside the loop.  You can still create the Matcher ahead of time and apply it to each line using the `reset()` method:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.asm"));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-z0-9_-]*)\\s+([A-Z]+)\\s+(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("");

while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String lineFromFile = sc.nextLine();
    if (m.reset(lineFromFile).find()) {
        System.out.printf("%-8s %-6s %s%n", m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3));
    }
}
```

As for your regex, the last part seemed to be too restrictive--it doesn't match your sample data, anyway.  I changed it to consume everything after the second whitespace gap.  I also simplified the first part and got rid of the unnecessary groups.

Comment: Thank you very much, mate! Your regex loooks a little bit more elegant :) Can you recommend any site / book to learn regex?

Comment: Sure.  [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and [this one](http://www.rexegg.com/) are great places to start, and if you're really serious, there's [The Book](http://regex.info/book.html)